# C function to add date adds gibberish

Tags: c

This program writes, edits and deletes tasks from a txt file. I'm having problems with my add task function (case (1)) in this situation. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
        switch(choice)
        {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter Task_Name: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Task_Name);

                printf("\nEnter Leader: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Leader);

                printf("\nEnter L_Email: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.L_Email);

                printf("\nEnter Member: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Member);

                printf("\nEnter Mem_Email: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Mem_Email);


                printf("\nEnter Begin_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);


                printf("\nEnter End_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);


                fwrite(&t,recsize,1,fp);


                printf("\nAdd another task(y/n) ");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
```

However, when I attempt to add a date with the above code I get gibberish in return. For example, when I type 11/11/1111 as the start date and 11/11/1111 as the end date, I get 6421994 and 6422005 in return. The same numbers shows up when I input any other date too.

To keep things reproducible I will have to include the entire code;

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<process.h>

#include<dos.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp, * ft;
    char another, choice;
    struct task
    {

        char Task_Name[50], Leader[50], L_Email[50], Member[50], Mem_Email[50],  Begin_date[11], End_date[11];

    };

    struct task t;

    int mm, dd, yyyy;

    char TaskName[40];

    long int recsize;
    fp = fopen("task.txt","rb+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fp = fopen("task.txt","wb+");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
        }
    }

    recsize = sizeof(t);
    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t **** Welcome to Personal System Management ****");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tMAIN MENU\n\t\t=====================\n\t\t[1] Add a new Task\n\t\t[2] View all Task\n\t\t[3] Update Task\n\t\t[4] Delete Task\n\t\t[5] Exit Program\n\t\t=================\n\t\t");
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        choice = getche();
        switch(choice)
        {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter Task_Name: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Task_Name);

                printf("\nEnter Leader: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Leader);

                printf("\nEnter L_Email: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.L_Email);

                printf("\nEnter Member: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Member);

                printf("\nEnter Mem_Email: ");
                scanf("%s", &t.Mem_Email);


                printf("\nEnter Begin_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);


                printf("\nEnter End_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);


                fwrite(&t,recsize,1,fp);


                printf("\nAdd another task(y/n) ");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            system("cls");
            rewind(fp);
            printf("Task Name|Leader|Leader Email|Member|Member Email|Begin Date|End Date");
            while(fread(&t,recsize,1,fp)==1)
            {
                printf("\n%s %s %s %s %s %d %d",t.Task_Name,t.Leader,t.L_Email,t.Member,t.Mem_Email,t.Begin_date,t.End_date);
            }
            getch();
            break;
        case '3':
            system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("Enter the task name you want to update: ");
                scanf("%s",TaskName);
                rewind(fp);
                while(fread(&t,recsize,1,fp)==1)
                {
                    if(strcmp(t.Task_Name,TaskName) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("Enter new Member name: ");
                        scanf("%s",&t.Member);
                        printf("Enter new Member Email: ");
                        scanf("%s",&t.Mem_Email);
                        printf("Enter new End Date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                        scanf("%d/%d/%d",&dd,&mm,&yyyy);
                        fseek(fp,-recsize,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&t,recsize,1,fp);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                printf("\nUpdate another task(y/n)");
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            system("cls");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("Enter the task name you want to delete: ");
                scanf("%s",TaskName);
                ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");
                rewind(fp);
                 while(fread(&t,recsize,1,fp) == 1)
                 {
                    if(strcmp(t.Task_Name,TaskName) != 0)
                    {
                        fwrite(&t,recsize,1,ft);
                    }
                 }
                 fclose(fp);
                 fclose(ft);
                 remove("task.txt");
                 rename("Temp.dat","task.txt");
                 fp = fopen("taxt.txt", "rb+");
                 printf("Delete another task(y/n)");
                 fflush(stdin);
                 another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '5':
            fclose(fp);
            exit(0);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You read values in three variables (`dd`, `mm` and `yyyy`) and you write the completely unrelated variable `t` in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never copying the dates into the structure.

```
                printf("\nEnter Begin_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);
                sprintf(t.Begin_date, "%02d/%02d/%04d", dd, mm, yyyy);

                printf("\nEnter End_date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dd,&mm,&yyyy);
                sprintf(t.End_date, "%02d/%02d/%04d", dd, mm, yyyy);
```

And since these are strings, you need to use `%s` when printing them, not `%d`.

```
                printf("\n%s %s %s %s %s %s %s",t.Task_Name,t.Leader,t.L_Email,t.Member,t.Mem_Email,t.Begin_date,t.End_date);
```